# How can I render a tree structure (recursive) using a django template?

Tags: python, django

I have a tree structure in memory that I would like to render in HTML using a Django template.

```
class Node():
  name = "node name"
  children = []
```

There will be some object `root` that is a `Node`, and `children` is a list of `Node`s. `root` will be passed in the content of the template.

I have found [this](http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/22/recursion-in-django-templates/) one discussion of how this might be achieved, but the poster suggests this might not be good in a production environment.

Does anybody know of a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the canonical answer is: "Don't".

What you should probably do instead is unravel the thing in your *view* code, so it's just a matter of iterating over (in|de)dents in the template. I think I'd do it by appending indents and dedents to a list while recursing through the tree and then sending that "travelogue" list to the template. (the template would then insert `<li>` and `</li>` from that list, creating the recursive structure with "understanding" it.)

I'm also pretty sure recursively including template files is really a *wrong* way to do it...

Comment: I don't see how this could possibly preserve the hierarchy of the original data unless you render the whole thing to HTML in your view.  Can you provide a more concrete example?

Comment: Sure. You make a list like [ 'in', 'in', 'blah', 'out', 'blah', 'out'] and then you loop over that in the template. If it's equal to 'in' you emit a li, 'out' you emit a /li and otherwise you just dump the text itself.

Comment: Any illumination on why that recursively building the menu is "really wrong?" Is it really that expensive?

Comment: Well, whether it's expensive or not in practice is sort of missing the point, the problem is that it is logic, and as such doesn't belong on the presentation side. It's more of a cleanliness thing than a performance thing.

Comment: While I agree with separating logic/presentation. This is one of the rare instances where the problem IS presentation. Because its a recursive thing being displayed. One of the problems with the logic/presentation divide is where to draw the line such that it doesnt actually CAUSE too much coupling on account of it requiring convoluted logic in the controller to get the dumbed down view to work. The controller in theory shouldnt have to understand the view, just know how to pass it data. But I guess its just one of those compromises with reality.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  It is trivial to create a simple inclusion template tag that recursively includes itself to display a tree of information as html.  As long as each recursive call does not call the database, and as long as proper caching is implemented, this need not present any performance concerns.  It is far messier to try to write the proper html as concatenated strings in the view; html code belongs in templates.

Answer (score 85):

Using `with` template tag, I could do tree/recursive list.

Sample code:

main template: assuming 'all_root_elems' is list of one or more root of tree

```
<ul>
{%for node in all_root_elems %} 
    {%include "tree_view_template.html" %}
{%endfor%}
</ul>
```

tree_view_template.html renders the nested `ul`, `li` and uses `node` template variable as below:

```
<li> {{node.name}}
    {%if node.has_childs %}
        <ul>
         {%for ch in node.all_childs %}
              {%with node=ch template_name="tree_view_template.html" %}
                   {%include template_name%}
              {%endwith%}
         {%endfor%}
         </ul>
    {%endif%}
</li>
```

Comment: Though I'm sure there are good reasons to not do what was asked, this answer actually circumvents the problem.  There is a performance hit, but using {% with %} to store the template name in a variable prevents the django template compiler from recursing infinitely.

Comment: Thanks! Simple, and works. Depending on the data structure you may not even need the loop in the main file (for the root objects)

Answer (score 50):

I'm too late.
All of you use so much unnecessary ***with*** tags, this is how I do recursive:

In the "main" template:

```
<!-- lets say that menu_list is already defined -->
<ul>
    {% include "menu.html" %}
</ul>
```

Then in `menu.html`:

```
{% for menu in menu_list %}
    <li>
        {{ menu.name }}
        {% if menu.submenus|length %}
            <ul>
                {% include "menu.html" with menu_list=menu.submenus %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: IMHO This is the cleanest and best abstraction in this thread.  Nice one Arthur!

Comment: Be aware that if you're passing QuerySet objects to your template, you need to call `all` on the query set object: `{% if menu.submenus.all|length %}`

Comment: Works like a charm. But I suppose this solution has only been available for a few years, see [the related Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3544). The other answers are just outdated.

Comment: Would `menu.submenus.count` be more efficient than getting the length that way?

Comment: Simple, clean and quick. Another addition in the "main" template, you might want to pass a context:

`<ul>
    {% include "menu.html" with menu_list=menu.submenus %}
</ul>
`

Comment: I'd up-vote, but you have 42 votes and I don't want to change that 8-)

Answer (score 20):

this might be way more than you need, but there is a django module called 'mptt' - this stores a hierarchical tree structure in an sql database, and includes templates for display in the view code.  you might be able to find something useful there.

here's the link : [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can do it. It's a little trick, 
passing the filename to {% include %} as a variable:

```
{% with template_name="file/to_include.html" %}
{% include template_name %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Nesting this way is nice and quick - I'm using it now - though I wonder if it's efficient (too lazy to test it myself). Anyone can chime in...

Answer (score 10):

Django has a built in template helper for this exact scenario:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list

Comment: Works if all you want to output is "<li>sometext</li>" for each item.  If you have a nested hierarchy of more complex items, and you (for example) want each item to be a link, then this tag isn't useful.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I wrote a template tag. I know there are other tags like this out there but I needed to learn to make custom tags anyway :) I think it turned out pretty well.

Read the docstring for usage instructions.

[github.com/skid/django-recurse](http://github.com/skid/django-recurse)

Comment: Perhaps this is the correct link? Profile for `skid` reads his last name is Jordanovski and this project description reads `a recursive django template tag`: https://github.com/skid/django-recurse

Comment: This is the perfect solution.. However what if we have to access other data inside of the looped category.. like: other information..

Answer (score 1):

Does no one like dicts ? I might be missing something here but it would seem the most natural way to setup menus. Using keys as entries and values as links pop it in a DIV/NAV and away you go !

From your base

```
# Base.html
<nav>
{% with dict=contents template="treedict.html" %}
 {% include template %}
{% endwith %}
<nav>
```

call this

```
# TreeDict.html
<ul>
{% for key,val in dict.items %}
 {% if val.items %}
  <li>{{ key }}</li>
  {%with dict=val template="treedict.html" %}
   {%include template%}
  {%endwith%}
 {% else %} 
  <li><a href="{{ val }}">{{ key }}</a></li>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

It haven't tried the default or the ordered yet perhaps you have ?

Answer (score 1):

correct this:

### root_comment.html

```
{% extends 'students/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block content %}

<ul>
{% for comment in comments %}
    {% if not comment.parent %}                   ## add this ligic
    {% include "comment/tree_comment.html" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

### tree_comment.html

```
<li>{{ comment.text }}
    {%if comment.children %}
        <ul>
         {% for ch in comment.children.get_queryset %}     # related_name in model
              {% with comment=ch template_name="comment/tree_comment.html" %}
                   {% include template_name %}
              {% endwith %}
         {% endfor %}
         </ul>
    {% endif %}
</li>
```

### for example - model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


# Create your models here.
class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        verbose_name = _('Comment')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Comments')

    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        parent_link=True,
        related_name='children',
        null=True,
        blank=True)

    text = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000,
        help_text=_('Please, your Comment'),
        verbose_name=_('Comment'),
        blank=True)

    public_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True)

    correct_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True)

    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: Brutal abuse of the include system, but it works! I like it! And the fact it makes recursion possible is leading me to rethink my stance that djangos templates are not turing complete.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue, however I had first implemented the solution using JavaScript, and just afterwards considered how I would have done the same thing in django templates.

I used the serializer utility to turn a list off models into json, and used the json data as a basis for my hierarchy.