# ORM / Template organization

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 4 models.. let's say:

```
Modal BigBox:
   small_boxes = ManyToMany
   .....

Model SmallBox
   .....

Model Item
   .....

Model Big_box_small_box_items:
   big_box = fk(BigBox)
   small_box = fk(SmallBox)
   Item = fk(Item)
   .....
```

In my template I want to go to a template for a big box and see a list of items in each small box.  I have a working page now but it involves lost of nesting logic inside the view and an inefficient number of database hits.

My head is swimming a bit as a hobbyist and I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you should be able to do something like:

```
{% for smallbox in bigbox.smallboxes.all %}
{{ smallbox.some_attribute }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40569127/4872140

Note that with the many to many, you don't use `_set` on smallboxes as you would for a normal foreign key relationship.

**INCORRECT:** (don't do this)

```
{% for smallbox in bigbox.smallboxes_set.all %}
{{ smallbox.some_attribute }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

There is some discussion on how to use/why the .all method call works in the [Django Template Language documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls). More specifically, on the [ManyToMany handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships).

EDIT:
After reading your comment, I see you have a slightly different issue than I originally read. I think you may need to add another loop inside of the outer loop. It is a little tough here due to the missing details in the models in the post. I'm going to suggest you rename `Big_box_small_box_items` to `BigBoxSmallBoxItems`, and rename the field from `Item` to `item`. Review the coding style and stick with it to save yourself some headaches later (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

```
{% for smallbox in bigbox.smallboxes.all %}
    {% for sbitem in smallbox.bigboxsmallboxitems_set.all %}
         {{ sbitem.item.your_item_attribute }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I doubt this will optimize your queries, and you may end up keeping what you've got. Depending on what you've already got in your view you may wish to review the `prefetch_related` tool (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I don't see how the given example would display the items in each small box.  The given link is helpful.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a list in my view and reduced database hits from 85 down to 10...

When given a big box..

```
    big_box_small_boxes = small_box.objects.filter(big_box=big_box)
    big_box_small_boxes_dict = {}
    big_box_list = []
    for small_box in big_box_small_boxes:
        big_box_item_dict = {
            "small_box" : small_box.name,
            "big_box_items" : Big_box_small_box_items.objects.filter(big_box=big_box, small_box=small_box).prefetch_related('item')
        }
        big_box_list.append(big_box_small_boxes_dict)
```

and then in the template...

```
{% for item in big_box_list %}
   {item.small_box}
   {% for big_box_item in item.big_box_items %}
      {% big_box_item.item.name %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor%}
```