# Django how to make ul li hierachy from a self reference model

Tags: python, django, tree, hierarchy

i have a model like this

```
class Unit(models.ModelForm):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length =  100)
    Parent = models.ForeignKey('self' , on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name = 'SubUnits')
```

i want to show hierarchy tree with `ul and li`  in the template.
first of all in the `views.py` i passed all Units with no parent which considered as Root Objects and then with a custom `filter tag` i want to generate hierarchy ul li tree

```
object1 ----|object 1.1 
            |object 1.2------| object 1.2.1
            |object 1.3 
objecte 2

object 3 ---| object 3.1
            | object 3.2---| object 3.2.1
```

in my custom tag i looks for a function that can generate infinite parent and child ul li for my root object.

Comment: See if this answer helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044/how-can-i-render-a-tree-structure-recursive-using-a-django-template/11644588#11644588

Answer (score 1):

finally i find my algorithm

models.py

```
class Hierarchy(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Parent = models.ForeignKey('self' , on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='SubHierarchy' , null=True , blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

my views.py:

```
#i pass root objects 
hierarchy = Hierarchy.objects.filter(Parent = None)
return render(request , 'index.html' , {
   'hierarchy' : hierarchy
 })
```

template :

```
 {% for unit in hierarchy %}
   {{unit|hierarchy|safe}}
 {% endfor %}
```

and my filter :

```
def assitant(obj):
    string = ''
    childs = obj.SubHierarchy.all()
    if childs.count() == 0:
        string = '<li>{}</li>'.format(obj)
    else:
        string += hierarchy(obj)

    return string


@register.filter
def hierarchy(unit):
    childs = unit.SubHierarchy.all()
    if childs.count() == 0:
        string = '<li>{}</li>'.format(unit)
    else:
        string = '<li>{}<ul>'.format(unit)
        for child in childs:
            string += assitant(child)
        string += '</ul></li>'
    return string
```