# Runtime error during django recursive template rendering

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to implement django recursive template rendering for getting users and their subordinates. However, I've got a ErrorRuntimeError at /admin/users/3
maximum recursion depth exceeded in **instancecheck**. I'm using django 1.9. The code is given below

The input is like that: `[{name: 'user1@mail.com', id: 1, next: True},
{name: 'user2@mail.com', id: 2, next: True}, {name: 'user3@mail.com', id: 3, next: False}]`

users_hierarchy.html

```
<ul>
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.name }}</li>
    {% if user.next %}
        <ul>
           {% include 'users/user_hierarchy.html' with data=user %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I expect a html such as:

```
<ul>
<li>user1@mail.com
    <ul>
        <li>user2@mail.com
    <ul>
         <li>user3@mail.com</li>
    </ul>
        </li>  
    </ul>
</li>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're passing the same user to the include, so the recursion can never return. You really need to pass the *next* user to the include; but there isn't a good way of getting it with the structure you have.

Comment: @DanielRoseman How could I pass the next user to the include? And what the better way to to organize my structure?

Comment: As I say, you can't do it in the template with the structure you have. Where does this data come from? Do you have control over the format? Ideally you want a structure like `{name: 'user1@mail.com', children: [{name: 'user2', children: [{name: 'user3'}]]}`.

Comment: The data is actually a RawQuerySet which is formed in for-loop by me to array of dictionaries, so I should change the form of input object and the code above will work?

Comment: Well, you would need to change the if statement to `if user.children` and the include to `with users=user.children`.

Comment: Of course, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**I explain why you are in an infinite recursion**

From [djanto include template docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> An included template is rendered within the context of the template that includes it.

That means you are iterating over `users` again and again:

```
<ul>
{% for user in users %}                 <-----(1)<------------------------<
    <li>{{ user.name }}</li>                                              |
    {% if user.next %}                                                    |
        <ul>                                                              |
           {% include 'users/user_hierarchy.html' with data=user %} --(2)->
```

At (1) you iterate over `users`. At first iteration you call the `include` (2). At this point you go to (1) (in nested included template) and start iteration again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how can I pass the next user within the same template?

Comment: What about to use django-mptt ? Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044/how-can-i-render-a-tree-structure-recursive-using-a-django-template